# How to Display resolved Names in Excel Formulas

Tags: excel

Is there an easy way for me to turn the following, if only for a second, into real SQL?:

```
=IFERROR(eagle("SELECT SUM("&selectedmonth&")/1000, ("& ytdformula & ")/1000 AS YTD, sum(Budget)*"&sMonthIndex&"/12000
             FROM ["&environment&"].[dbo].[SD_"&selectedyear&"_flat" & IF(selectedCurrency="USD","","_EUR") &"]
             WHERE 1=1
             "&IF(selectedDepartment="All",""," AND department = '"&selectedDepartment&"'")&" 
             "&IF(selectedproduct="All",""," AND product = '"&selectedproduct&"'")&"      
             "&IF(AND(getMacro=FALSE,getRatesNSU=FALSE),
               IF(selecteddivision="All",""," AND division='"&selecteddivision&"'"),
               IF(getMacro=TRUE," AND (division = 'Commodities' OR division = 'FX Products' OR division = 'Rate Products')"," AND (division = 'Rate Products' OR product = 'IB Non-Strategic Unit')"))&"
             "&IF(exclSMG=FALSE,""," AND Division <> 'Systematic Market Making'")&"
             "&IF(selectedsubdivision="All",""," AND subdivision = '"&selectedsubdivision&"'")&"
             "&IF(selectedcluster="All",""," AND cluster = '"&selectedcluster&"'")&"    
             "&IF(selectedregion="All",""," AND region = '"&selectedregion&"'")&"
             "&IF(selectedBiz="All",""," AND business_unit IN "&selectedBiz),connectionString),0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the word stop in front of this line of code then paste the following into the VBA Immediate window with a question mark in front of it.

```
?"SELECT SUM("&selectedmonth&")/1000, ("& ytdformula & ")/1000 AS YTD, sum(Budget)*"&sMonthIndex&"/12000
         FROM ["&environment&"].[dbo].[SD_"&selectedyear&"_flat" & IF(selectedCurrency="USD","","_EUR") &"]
         WHERE 1=1
         "&IF(selectedDepartment="All",""," AND department = '"&selectedDepartment&"'")&" 
         "&IF(selectedproduct="All",""," AND product = '"&selectedproduct&"'")&"      
         "&IF(AND(getMacro=FALSE,getRatesNSU=FALSE),
           IF(selecteddivision="All",""," AND division='"&selecteddivision&"'"),
           IF(getMacro=TRUE," AND (division = 'Commodities' OR division = 'FX Products' OR division = 'Rate Products')"," AND (division = 'Rate Products' OR product = 'IB Non-Strategic Unit')"))&"
         "&IF(exclSMG=FALSE,""," AND Division <> 'Systematic Market Making'")&"
         "&IF(selectedsubdivision="All",""," AND subdivision = '"&selectedsubdivision&"'")&"
         "&IF(selectedcluster="All",""," AND cluster = '"&selectedcluster&"'")&"    
         "&IF(selectedregion="All",""," AND region = '"&selectedregion&"'")&"
         "&IF(selectedBiz="All",""," AND business_unit IN "&selectedBiz),connectionString),0)
```

The Immediate window will concatenate all the variables and literals into the SQL String that it is attempting to execute.

IF there is errors in the SQL, you should be able to copy the SQL into the QBE editor to get the error message the compiler cannot reconcile.

Comment: Hi, This sounds great, however I can't quite get this to work as you suggest. Could you possibly clarify? I've tried a simple version: ?stop"SELECT TOP 10 ISNULL(it_project_name,'Unassigned') FROM ["&environment&"].[dbo].[SD_"&selectedyear&"_flat"& IF(selectedCurrency="USD","","_CHF") &"]
             WHERE 1=1;"

Comment: If you have not used the Immediate window before, it is possible to use the question mark to return code variable values and object properties. To  get the question mark to return the completed concatenation above, you must run the code that has the concatenation in it and stop at the line that is not working. While the code is in debug mode (indicated by a yellow highlight on the active line in the vba code window) you can then run your code in the immediate window . Doing so will concatenate all the variables in your SQL statement, replacing them with the underlying values.

Comment: Also remove the word stop in the immediate window, because it will cause an error. If you know how to use the immediate window my apologies. If you do not, reply back and we can provide some simple examples on how to use it to debug your SQL.